# Coldfusion - can you treat a string as list with no delimiters?

Tags: string, coldfusion

I previously thought that you can take an ordinary string and treat it as a list with "" as the delimiter, but CF doesn't seem to allow that. Doing something like this:

```
<cfloop list="abcdef" delimiters="" index="thisLetter">
    <cfoutput>#thisLetter#</cfoutput><br>
</cfloop>
```

only results in 1 iteration of the loop, and an output of the whole string on one line. Not what's desired.

I did find you can use the Java `string.split()` method with a "" delimiter:

```
<cfset myArray = "abcdef".split("")>
<cfdump var="#myArray#">
```

But then the first element in the resulting array is an empty string, so there's an extra step in removing that from the array.

Is there a more elegant way to iterate over all the chars in this string without having to do any special string manipulation first, and without having to use `left()`, `right()`, or `mid()`?

Comment: Try using chr(30) as your delimiter.

Comment: `<cfset myArray = " abcdef".trim().split("") />`

Comment: @AlexBaban The empty first element is a "feature" in Java <= 7, and not related to an actual whitespace. It is "corrected" in Java >= 8.

Comment: As @Alex already suggested, update to Java 8 or higher.  Until then, you can code it as `<cfset myArray = listCompact(arrayToList("abcdef".split(""), ",")).split(",")>` assuming you're using Lucee.  The `listCompact()` function is not valid for ACF.  See example [here](https://trycf.com/gist/05a83665779207fc1d3b267dc735cbf0/lucee?theme=monokai)

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using Java's [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()):

```
<cfset myString = "aäй漢か">
<cfset theChars = myString.toCharArray()>

<cfloop array="#theChars#" index="char">
    <cfoutput>#char#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: An empty delimiter used with LIstToArray(textString, "") accomplished the same thing, but you'll encounter issues with multibyte UTF-8 characters (ie, emojis). I've had some success with normalizing characters to NFC format in regards to character counting & romanization. https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2840-trying-to-understand-unicode-normalization-in-coldfusion-and-java.htm

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is what I was looking for: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/307-ask-ben-iterating-over-the-characters-in-a-string.htm

Using mid() is simplest, and isn't too cumbersome. Still, would be nice to be able to use CF list loop with delimiters="".